# Значення слова "фурделя"

Tags: значення-слів

[Фразеологічний словник української мови](http://slovopedia.org.ua/49/53408/360909.html)

> **і (рі́дна) ма́ти не впізнає́ (не пізнає́) / не впізна́є (не пізна́є)**
>   кого і без додатка. Хтоcь дуже змінився на вигляд, зовні.
>   *В нас і таке бува: поїде дівка з села, потиняється рік-два, а потім повертається такою, що й рідна мати її не пізнає. Моди всякої
>   повигадує… Та обріже косу, накрутить на голові таку **фурделю**, кури
>   лякаються* (Ю. Мокрієв)

Цікавить значення слова ***"фурделю"***.

В словниках не знайшла слова "фурделя".

Comment: Дуже схоже на _хурделя_.

Comment: @follower, по-моєму, це майже відповідь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Фурделя -- хуртовина, завірюха. Це слово можна знайти наприклад у вірші Тетяни Винник "Метелиця":

> Заметь, сніговій, хуртеча –
>
> Нажахалася малеча –
>
> Заметіль, фурделя, хвижа
>
> В димарі горлає хижо!

Comment: додайте, будь ласка, посилання на словник з поясненням слова "хурделя" або "хуртовина". Зніму мінус і поставлю плюс.